# how to change promise.all to promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I have two api calls in promise ,so i have used promise.all and it is working fine.

Now i have one api call is enough to get the results but still i am using promise.all it is working fine.

I try to use promise instead of promise.all(here i  used one api call )

my code here :

```
Promise.all([getCall()])
          .then(res => {
            if (res[0].errorObject) {
              props.Error(res[0]);
            } else { 
              <!----code here--->
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err); 
          });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
getCall()
  .then(res => {
    if (res.errorObject) {
      props.Error(res);
    } else { 
      // <!----code here--->
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err); 
  });
```

Answer (score -2):

You can using fetch()
like this for example :

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((r) => {
        // save data from fetch request to state
        setData(r);
      });
  },[url]);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).